# decltype with C++ array

Tags: c++

I have a question about `decltype`. For the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int a[3];
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype((a)), int(&)[3]> << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(a + 0), int*> << std::endl;
}
```

All of the outputs are 1. But as cppreference said:

> If the argument is any other expression of type `T`, and if the value category of `expression` is lvalue (or pvalue), then decltype yields `T&` (or `T`);

I don't understand why `decltype((a))` is `int(&)[3]`, since

1. `a` is an array variable, which is not an lvalue
2. `(a)` is an expression, so I think `decltype((a))` should return its type, which should be decayed as `int*`, as the second output shows.

So basically, I don't understand the difference between `(a)` and `a + 0` when using `decltype`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `a` is an array variable, which is not a lvalue

`a` is both a variable name and an expression. Variables themselves don't have value categories, but when used as an expression, it's an lvalue.

`(a)` is an expression, completely equivalent to expression `a`. `(a)` is not a variable name, obviosuly.

> I think `decltype((a))` should return its type

As you quote says, for expressions `decltype` also encodes their value category in the type it returns, by adding `&`, `&&`, or nothing to it. Since `(a)` is an lvalue, `&` is added.

> should be decayed as `int*`

Array-to-pointer decay doesn't always happen. It happens during most uses of arrays, but not all of them.

In particular, it doesn't happen when passing an array to `decltype`.

> as the second output shows

In the second case, applying `+` to the array forces its decay to a pointer.

The resulting pointer is a prvalue, so the reported type is not a reference.

Answer (score 3):

[`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) has two forms:

- `decltype` ( *entity* )
- `decltype` ( *expression* )

When the argument is an *id-expression* like `a`, it falls into the first form, and `decltype` yields the referenced type itself, even though an expression `a` is an lvalue.

By wrapping `a` as `(a)` we force it to fall into the second form, in which case `decltype` yields the actual type of the expression, which is an lvalue reference to `a`.

Array-to-pointer decaying doesn't occur in `decltype` context, hence we end up with a reference to an array type. But it does occur in expressions like `+`, in which case we end up with a pointer type.

Comment: So when does the array-to-pointer decaying occur?

Comment: @WeiLi Off the top of my head: it occurs in all cases except when the array is: unused; passed to `sizeof`, `decltype`, etc; when `&` is applied to it, when it's passed to a function that accepts a reference to an array.